# Создание экрана по шаблону

Tags: android, gui

Здравствуйте. Никогда не сталкивался с программированием GUI и поэтому на первый взгляд элементарная задача создания экрана по шаблону вызвала некоторые трудности.
Ниже сам шаблон:

[image: Шаблон]

Сама суть вопроса в том, что использовать для такого открывающегося списка меню? Возможно есть уже некоторые готовые патерны?Просто все поиски в google при моей формулировке вопроса приводят меня только к использованию spinner, что совсем не то. Буду рад любой подсказке

Comment: Ищите по запросу  `expandable recyclerview`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/5071
Похожее решение, Android Arsenal открываем и ищем нужную реализацию